# send an email from a HTML/CSS/JS app

Tags: javascript, html, css, single-page-application

I am developping a mobile HTML/CSS/JS app with a contact form.
For now I use a "mailto" to send the message, but it is not efficient because the user is sent to his email app before sending.
How can I send the message directly from the app ?

thanks

Comment: You will need to write server-side code to achieve this. SMTP server methods in C#, for example.

Comment: You cannot send email with pure Java Script from client side.

Comment: Or you can use 3rd party mail service with JavaScript API such as Mailchimp or similar ones

Comment: @DeeMac I don't understand because I have no server, it is just an app. Robert ok I am gonna try to check mailchimp out

Comment: Mailchimp doesn't seem to be easily integrable within an HTML/CSS/JS app, is it? I really need something simple to run client side (from my app).

Comment: Please let me know if you found your solution.I am stuck with same problem.

Comment: No I didn't find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Write an application that runs on the server of you website.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any server side code then you either need to use any third party Javascript application.    (API)

or you can try this also :

```
<a href="mailto:emailaddress">Email</a>
```

1) For third party API you can try this also (Never tried it but looks good enough)

[www.mycontactform.com](http://www.mycontactform.com)

2) Mail Chimp (as Robert suggested)

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this purely from javascript. You will need a server side component to connect to an SMTP server in order to be able to send your email.

Even if you were able to somehow develop an SMTP client for javascript, the security risks involved would much outweigh the advantages. All your users will need to do to send email as you, is to go through your javascript code and get your SMTP credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it by client side language.  Use server side language like php to do that.

```
<?php
     mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters);
?>
```

Copied from w3school